# Prove that $(S')' = S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I would like to ask if my solution, which is presented below, is correct.

$S' = ${$x \in U: x \notin S$}  
$(S')' = ${$x  \in U: x \notin S'$} 
$ \implies (S')' = \hspace{1mm}${$x \in U: (x \notin U  \hspace{1mm} or  \hspace{1mm}  x \notin S')$} 
$ \implies (S')' = \hspace{1mm} ${$x \in U: (x \notin U  \hspace{1mm} or  \hspace{1mm}  (x \in S \hspace{1mm} or \hspace{1mm}x \notin U)$} 
$x \notin U $ is always false 
$\implies (S')' = \hspace{1mm} ${$x \in U: x \in S $} 
$\implies (S')' = \hspace{1mm}S$

Kindly suggest any necessary changes if this doesn't work.

Comment: If $S \subset U$, so if you want to prove $(S')'=S$. You need to show that $(S')'\subset S$ and $S\subset (S')'$.

Comment: @Ramanujan can you provide me with some idea on how to get started with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/937172/798113

Comment: @Ramanujan , yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More directly :

$$x \in S' \Longleftrightarrow x \notin S$$

So applying this to $S'$, you get

$$x \in (S')' \Longleftrightarrow x \notin S' \Longleftrightarrow x \in S$$

So $(S')'=S$.